# contract call from a contract fails (succeeds in VM)

Tags: return-value, solidity, remix

The following test contracts work as expected Via Remix when deployed and run in the JavaScript VM but when run with the "Injected Web3" the generation of the secondary contract TestA02 T2 is generated and populated as expected, all get functions called via the primary contract TestA01 return "0" values. If you copy the address of the TestA02 contract and address it directly from Remix, the expected values are returned. Code follows below.

Is this a bug or a misunderstanding on my part?

Instructions:
Using Remix from Mist Version 0.10.0 Compile and Deploy the Primary Contract CODE TestA01.

Call the genEntry function passing any address.

Then call any of the get functions.

CODE:

Primary Contract CODE TestA01:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

import "browser/TestA02.sol";

contract TestA01 {

    TestA02 T2;

    constructor() public {
        T2 = new TestA02();
    }

    function genEntry(address a) public {
        T2.add(a);
    }

    function get() public view returns(address) {return(T2.get(0));}
    function get(uint i) view public returns(address) {return(T2.get(i));}

    function getSize() public view returns(uint) {return(T2.getSize());}

    function getT2() public view returns(address) {return(address(T2));}
}
```

Secondary Contract CODE TestA02:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;


contract TestA02 {

    uint _size;
    mapping(uint => address) private arrayMap;

    constructor() public {
        _size = 0;
    }

    function add(address a) public {
        arrayMap[_size++] = a;
    }

    function get() public view returns(address) {return(arrayMap[0]);}
    function get(uint i) public view returns(address) {return(arrayMap[i]);}

    function getSize() public view returns(uint) {return(_size);}
}
```

Comment: To make sure I’m understanding the question correctly...Working with `TestA02` directly is working as expected. But, using `TestA02` when called from `TestA01` is always returning empty results? After deploying `TestA01`, you’re adding addresses via `genEntry()`, correct?

Comment: Correct. I deploy TestA01 which creates TestA02 and functions to access TestA02's functions via GenEntry and the gets. You can see that GenEntry works by getting the deployed address of TestA02 from the getT2 function and using the @address deploy option for remix to interact with the TestA02 functions. But those same functions return 0's via TestA01's get functions. I don't understand why.

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce your issue. I deployed your `TestA01` contract to Rinkeby using "Injected Web3" in Remix (contract address: 0xe928b76ed00dc25bf665684f579ce6b90c55fd41) then called `genEntry()` passing in an address. After mining the transaction, `get()` returns the previously passed in address as expected.

Comment: I have just been able to verify your conclusion. You are correct, this contract works on both the JavaScript VM and Rinkeby. It does not however work on the private chain I was using. Any Ideas what makes for this strange behavior? Why would a private chain behave differently than these other chains?

Comment: My (best) guess is you don't have mining turned on or your difficulty is set so high in your `genesis.json` that it takes a very long time to create new blocks. Check which block number you're on before calling `genEntry()` then verify it increments after submitting the transactions and before calling `get()`. (But, you said you can deploy ok which contradicts this, but that's all I've got at this point)

Comment: It is not the mining. I can get the address of the TestA02 contract deployed by TestA01 via the getT2 function and set Remix to talk to it directly and the data is in there. But calls to the pass through gets of TestA01 always return 0.